# Audio stream from device's microphone using Phonegap

Tags: serialization, phonegap-plugins, audio-streaming, cordova-plugins, microphone

I would like to use (or create) a phonegap/cordova plugin to access the device's audio input as a stream. Is this even possible? I noticed [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Plugins) that the native code output has to be returned as JSON to pass it to JS. Does this mean that we cannot pass streams? It isn't possible to serialise a stream is it?

The existing plugins such as [this one](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) captures the audio and writes it to a file.